# Cannot compress any file

Tags: macos

I get a popup "The contents list can’t be created for compressing."
every time when I try to compress a file.

And also thumbnail preview is not working.

I am sure if both issues are related but they both happened today.

I've tried repairing disk permissions, deleting finder plist, restart but none of this works.

I am running Yosemite 10.10.1

Any suggestion?

=================================

**I went to Apple Store and they can't fix this.
They reinstall the Mac for me.**

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: is it the same file or any file?

Comment: ACLs issue perhaps? Though idk how to clear them in Terminal, I'd use Cocktail etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. Just tried Cocktail but it didn't help.

Comment: What are you trying to compress ? [on Unix all is file] However, you can put your "file" into a directory and compress this one.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin Thanks I can still compress a file from command line: zip and tar. I was able to do it with the right-click until the day I asked the question. (And I know I can put a file in a "directory" and compress it.)

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands in order in Terminal. Same issue for me and fixed it. I'm not sure what's causing it but I have to run it every so often to fix it.

```
sudo mkdir /private/tmp
sudo chmod 0777 /private/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading The Unarchiver on the App Store and create the zip file with that. If that does not work go into your terminal and type `killall Finder`. That terminal command should deal with the thumbnail issues and hopefully the archiving problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this is because you don't have enough disk space left on the drive you're creating your backup.